# TextField dentro de una Row en Flutter

Tags: flutter, layout, textfield

Estoy obteniendo un error de renderización, cuando compilo mi código Flutter, el método es el siguiente:

```
Widget _formWidget() {
return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    _entryField("NÚMERO DE TARJETA", "1234 5678 9012 3456"),
    SizedBox(height: 10),
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        _blockField("FECHA DE EXP.", "MM/YY"),
        _blockField("CVV", "123"),
      ],
    ),
    SizedBox(height: 10),
    _entryField("PAÍS", "México"),
    SizedBox(height: 10),
    _entryField("CÓDIGO POSTAL", "123456"),
  ],
);}
```

El error se produce al no vizualizar los dos bloques que se encuentran dentro de Row, el Widget _blockField contiene elsiguiente código:

```
Widget _blockField(String title, String hint) {
return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            fontSize: 10,
            color: Color(0x99000000)),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 10,
      ),
      new Flexible(
          child: TextField(
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: hint,
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  fillColor: Color(0xfff3f3f4),
                  filled: true))),
    ],
  ),
);}
```

Leí que el problema radica en que TextField no tiene un ancho especifico y es por ello que se debe colocar dentro de un componente Flexible; así:

```
Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(child: TextField()),
        Flexible(child: TextField()),
      ],
    ),
```

¿Cómo debería implementarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolverlo solo es necesario mantener los componentes en Flexible del Widget _formWidget(), eliminando la asignación de flexible al TexField directamente.

Y no olvidar la asignación de child a todo el widget:

```
Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(child: _blockField("FECHA DE EXP.", "MM/YY")),
        Flexible(child: _blockField("CVV", "123")),
      ],
    ),
```